What movie does the famous line 'We didn't get dressed up for nothing' come from?
I have always wondered, I have heard it so many times, I have read it out of a book I read called Uncommon Soldier By Chris Masters, the chapter:
'We didn't get dressed up for nothing'.
Fact is the book never mentioned where it was from.
I have heard it is from a movie and I have done some searching and I have not found it.
I have heard it extensively from my parents saying it, other people related to military saying it and they say they got it from a movie but no one is willing to say.
What movie is the famous line from?

"I have done some searching" Er, no offense, but Googling the phrase immediately turns up the name of the movie it's from.

It didn't do that for me, instead, it came up with all sorts of different links to random pages.

Oh wow, why am I getting so many downvotes on my questions?

That line has likely been said in more than a couple of movies, but Braveheart (1995) uses that line.
Here's a clip:



